# swt tutorials or guides

Tags: java, architecture, swt

I have some years experience with swing and feel comfortable that I understand the architecture.

Now I need to get up to speed on SWT rather quickly.

What would you recommend I study from online sources or books so I can get my head around the SWT architecture quickly ? I'm really starting from scratch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[SWT Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/).  That's pretty much all you need to get started.  There are some papers on SWT at eclipse.org as well.  A lot is pretty similar to Swing so you will be up to speed in no time.

Comment: Cool bananas, when I woke up I kicked myself for asking such a dumb question. I might need an SO filter option like : do not allow this idjit to post questions before midday.

Comment: No worries, the easy ones help to build rep; enjoy your SWT.  You will love it after Swing.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to use utils like GridLayoutFactory and GridDataFactory from JFace.
They really reduce swt interface developement time.

Answer (score 2):

The pdf's from this site are very good: [www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse](http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse/)

Also there are some snippets on [www.java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CatalogSWT-JFace-Eclipse.htm) (similar to those from the eclipse site)

If you used swing and now you want to start with SWT, this book shows you the differences: [SWT Eye for the Swing Guy](http://developers.sun.com/learning/javaoneonline/2006/desktop/TS-3853.pdf)

Comment: Thx dude, found the Manitoba site this am from the Eclipse site.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that the [Eclipse Visual Editor](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) is being worked on again. This is a useful learning tool, even if you don't want to use it to develop your GUIs because of the way it translates `WYSIWYG -> code` and `code -> WYSIWYG` (within certain limitations, of course - it isn't magic). Useful for seeing the relationship between the code and the results.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at it last week - and realised I had to know what the heck was under the covers if it was going to be any use to me !

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [swtxml](http://code.google.com/p/swtxml/) plugin for eclipse? I find it (even with its faults) a small sweet tool. Lets you design your Composites and so on using xml.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2016/11/eclipse-swt-tutorial.html) gives you quick overview on swt.